# bower install fails because of something I'm not installing

Tags: angularjs, bower

this is the bower dependency:

```
dependencies": [
        "angular#>=1.0.8 <1.2.0-rc.1",
        "restangular#1.1.6",
        "angular-bootstrap#0.6.0",
        "jquery#>=1.10.0 <1.11.0",
        "momentjs#2.2.1",
        "requirejs#2.1.8",
        "bootstrap#2.3.2",
        "underscore#>=1.5.2 <1.6.0",
        "angular-cookies",
        "angular-translate",
        "angular-translate-loader-static-files",
        "angular-resource",
        "angular-sanitize",
        "angular-mocks",
        "angular-scenario",
        "angular-loader",
        "FbAngular"

    ],
    "license": "All Rights Reserved",
    "private": true,
    "ignore": [
        "**/.*",
        "node_modules",
        "bower_components",
        "app/lib",
        "test",
        "tests"
    ]
}
```

but when I try to run from the command line:

```
bower install angular-translate
```

I get this strange output:

> bower angular#*                 cached
>   https://github.com/angular/bower-angular.git#1.0.8 bower angular#*
>   validate 1.0.8 against https://github.com/angular/bower-angular.git#*
>   bower angular#>=1               cached
>   https://github.com/angular/bower-angular.git#1.2.0-rc.3 bower
>   angular#>=1             validate 1.2.0-rc.3 against
>   https://github.com/angular/bower-angular.git#>=1 bower
>   angular-translate#*   not-cached
>   https://github.com/PascalPrecht/bower-angular-translate.git#* bower
>   angular-translate#*      resolve
>   https://github.com/PascalPrecht/bower-angular-translate.git#* bower
>   angular-translate#*     download
>   https://github.com/PascalPrecht/bower-angular-translate/archive/1.1.0.tar.gz
>   bower angular-translate#*      extract archive.tar.gz bower
>   angular-translate#*     resolved
>   https://github.com/PascalPrecht/bower-angular-translate.git#1.1.0
>   bower 8#angular-cookies      ENOTFOUND Package 8 not found

I get it for everything I install with bower - whats wrong?

Comment: Didn't seem worthy of a downvote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`dependencies` should be an object literal, not an array.

See  [bower](https://github.com/bower/bower#defining-a-package).

Comment: True enough! Also Thank you for this great tool! (we would love to be able to add customized installations path (some to lib, some to vendor, etc)..